# Debian Jessie updates failed

Tags: updates, debian-jessie

from 3-4 days I'm trying to update my debian Jessie, but I'm getting always the same output errors.
[image: debian update error]

I also tried with the commands

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get clean
```

and so on, but nothing is helping me.
It seems like if the server is down, but I don't know why and how to fix it. I really need those updates. I thought that the Jessie version went out of updates but I was wrong.
Could anyone help me please?
thank you so much.

Comment: This question would be better suited for SE sites like Serverfault or Superuser.

Comment: Probably you are right. Thanks for the suggestion, however I found a solution by myself, just by using other mirrors. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Because Debian removed wheezy and jessie from ftp.[country].debian.org to archive.debian.org

Reference:
https://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&p=1201633
https://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=showheadline&story=7882

You have to update you /etc/apt/source.list file